# Automated XP Mode install

Tags: powershell, windows-xp-mode, silent-install

I manage a conference lab environment, and one thing we would like to do is install the 1.0 version of our primary software, as a bit of a nostalgia playground. The thing is, this old version really doesn't get along with newer versions of .NET and C++, and we need those for the current version of the software.

What I would love to do is automate the installation of XP Mode and that particular program, either get an XP Mode VM pre-configured and stored on our NAS ready to copy, or actually automate an XP Mode based installation on each machine. But thus far my Google-Fu has found nothing about automating this. Am I barking up an empty tree, or should I keep looking?

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f31fddb1-b480-433a-a433-2dbcfeafc2ed/looking-for-silent-installation-switches-parameters-for-windowsxpmodeenusexe?forum=w7itprovirt